# Querying disk usage without impacting the performance

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which allows users to upload files. These files can be uploaded via browser or any tool for bulk uploading. I need to monitor the storage where files are actually being stored and prevent uploading if storage reaches a certain threshold.

But the API available to query disk usage on network share is an unmanaged call which could be costly and will result in slow performance.

Should I make these calls asycn? (If yes, should I do this using dedicated thread or a thread from threadpool?)
Should I not get usage stats on each request? (Which is acceptable but how should I manage this?)

Comment: What makes you think calls to unmanaged code is that costly and hurtful for performance? have you actually measured it to see if it's a problem?

Comment: It's probably more relevant that it is a call to query disk usage, and not that it is an unmanaged call. Querying disk usage is expensive, no matter what language you're doing it in. Of course, by expensive, I mean relative to other operations - like concatenating a string. It's still not that painful. You can issue the request for disk usage synchronously - after all, you don't want to proceed if it's too high - by the same reasoning, you should issue it for each request. Is the disk space dedicated to this application?

Comment: @phyllis: It is expensive and I can't afford a blocking call here. We only need to send a warning notification if free space is less than a certain size. So in that case, i guess, we can go for a non blocking call. And no, there no dedicated space for application.